# NullPointerException on synchronized threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Ok I've been working on this homework for some hours now.
Sorry If the english isn't good I just translated from google.

"For our homework synchronized threads must develop a simulation of wildlife. There will be a single kind of animal . We will have a very particular kind of gorillas. We will have an area ( 20 x 20 Array ) . Initially we will create 5 male and 5 female gorillas . Then we must put in random positions. All gorillas are going to move in the Array, can not have more than three gorillas in a space. For the coexistence of these gorillas must follow these rules:

If two gorillas are found in a single cell and they are the same sex one of the two gorilla dies (this should be done randomly ) If two gorillas have a different sex, a new one is born (sex must also be selected at random ) . And they should continue their separate ways . We must identify the share and synchronize all the threads."

And I did this: 
Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InformacionGorila info1 = new InformacionGorila(true, 1);
    InformacionGorila info2 = new InformacionGorila(true, 2);
    Gorilas gorila1 = new Gorilas(info1);
    Gorilas gorila2 = new Gorilas(info2);       
    gorila1.start();
    gorila2.start();
}
```

InformacionGorila class:

```
public class InformacionGorila {

private boolean genero;
private String sexo;
private int id;

public InformacionGorila(boolean genero, int id) {
    this.genero = genero;
    this.id = id;
    DecisionDeGenero(genero);
}

private void DecisionDeGenero(boolean genero) {
    if (genero == true) {
        setSexo("Macho");
    } else if (genero == false) {
        setSexo("Hembra");
    }
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public boolean getGenero() {
    return genero;
}

public void setGenero(boolean genero) {
    this.genero = genero;
}

public String getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

private void setSexo(String sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
} }
```

Gorilas class:

```
public class Gorilas extends Thread {

private final InformacionGorila info;
private Territorio terr;

public Gorilas(InformacionGorila info) {
    this.info = info;
}

public InformacionGorila getInfo() {
    return info;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        terr.Convivencia(info);
        System.out.println("Gorila: " + info.getId() + " Genero: " + info.getSexo());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}  }
```

And Territorio class:

```
public class Territorio {

public boolean ocupado = false;
public int cont = 0;
Gorilas[][] gorilas = new Gorilas[20][20];

public synchronized void Convivencia(InformacionGorila info) {
    while (ocupado) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Territorio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
    cont++;
    if (cont == 2) {
        ocupado = true;
    }

    jaula(info);
}
int j = 0;
int cont2 = 0;

private synchronized void jaula(InformacionGorila info) {
    String g = null;
    String h = null;
    while (cont2 != 2) {
        if (j == 0) {
            g = info.getSexo();
            j++;
        } else if (j == 1) {
            h = info.getSexo();
        }
        cont2++;
    }
    decision(g, h);

}

public void decision(String g, String h) {
    if (g.equals(h)) {
        InformacionGorila info = new InformacionGorila(true, 11);
        Gorilas gorila = new Gorilas(info);
        gorila.start();
    }
}  }
```

Of course is not finished yet but when I try to test it I get nullpointer exception when the program comes to call `terr.Convivencia(info);` in Gorilas class method run. Can someone tell me why? What is wrong? or what am I doing wrong?

These are the exception:

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" Exception in thread "Thread-1" >java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at hilossync.Gorilas.run(Gorilas.java:28)
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at hilossync.Gorilas.run(Gorilas.java:28)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *declared* Territorio terr, but not *initialized* it, making it a null object.

It should read more like

```
Territorio terr = new Territorio();
```

Comment: Oh! Yeah! Thank you sir! Didn't see that! haha